# How to add lighttpd in yocto

Tags: php, iot, yocto, lighttpd

I want to add lighttpd and php-cgi in my "rpi-basic-image". I have in my `bblayers.conf`:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/osboxes/Desktop/SI_Labs/Lab_06/poky/meta \
  /home/osboxes/Desktop/SI_Labs/Lab_06/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/osboxes/Desktop/SI_Labs/Lab_06/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "
BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= " \
  /home/osboxes/Desktop/SI_Labs/Lab_06/poky/meta \
  /home/osboxes/Desktop/SI_Labs/Lab_06/poky/meta-yocto \
  "
```

In `meta`, I have a directory called `recipes-extended/lighttpd`. I read that I must add in my `layer.conf`

```
CORE_EXTRA_IMAGES_INSTALL += "lighttpd-module-fastcgi"
```

or

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "lighttpd-module-fastcgi"
```

but the image still doesn't have lighttpd. I don't want to add apt in my image.
Can somebody make me understand what I have done wrong?

P.S. I followed instructions from https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage, but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` (c.f. http://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL) or `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " lighttpd-module-fastcgi"` (you are missing a leading space in the string). They should NOT be in any `layer.conf`, at worst in `conf/local.conf`, at best in your image recipe.